# How can i swipe on a table cell and make it call a function?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How can i swipe my finger on a table cell and call a function ( in which i push a view controller to my navigation controller ) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *g = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellWasSwiped:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:g];
    [g release];
}
```

Then implement the method to handle the swipe:

```
- (void)cellWasSwiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)g {
    NSLog(@"Swiped");
}
```

Comment: It seems you also need to set this, `g.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;`

Comment: You may also want to add:
`CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:TableView];

  
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [TableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

  if (indexPath == nil) {
   //Not on a cell
  }
  else {
                        //On a cell, use indexPath to do something.
                }`

Comment: @NightLeopard In the example the gesture recognizer is added to the cell itself, so if it gets triggered it's always from a cell.

Comment: What's the point of adding the gesture recognizer to the cell itself, though? Doing that means you can't tell which cell was swiped. It's easier, and more CPU and memory efficient to create only one for the whole table view and get the cell dynamically.

Comment: @NightLeopard The gesture recognizer has a `view` property that contains the view it's attached to, in this case the table view cell. As for effiecieny, it could be better to set the recognizer for the table view itself, but only Instruments can tell. :)